# kendo chart arabic title (RTL) issue

Tags: canvas, kendo-ui, dojo, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-chart

Display chart title in **"Arabic language"**

[image]

Expected Chart title **"(متوسط الدخل السنوي للأفراد (2005"**

As per the kendo recommendation, they ask us to use direction RTL

```
  <div class="k-rtl">
<div id="chart"></div>
</div>
```

After using also keeps the same issue.

Suggest us to solve the issue

**Sample dojo created**  [Click view demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/UGoHiN)

Comment: if you are talking about the parentheses around 2005, you have them in the wrong place in your title property of the dojo...

Comment: @ezanker Since its Placed in the correct place. With the same title if we use like this  "<p style='direction:rtl'>Arabic content</p>" it was working. Same thing not working with the canvas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for this is just we need to contact the arabic empty character at the end.

**"\u200f" we used the arabic empty space encoding to solve this issue.**

```
       function OnChartRender(e)
        {
          var chart = e.sender;
          var newTitle = chart.options.title.text;// "Arabic title goes here"
          newTitle = newTitle + "\u200f";
          chart.options.title.text = newTitle;    
          chart.refresh(); 
       }
```